# move_uploaded_file Issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form which has textboxes and has certain values. and i have a video upload file in that form. I am using **move_uploaded_file** function in which i am successfully uploading the **Video File** to DB and storing in a Specific folder and displaying as Thumbnail in a form.

Again i am successfully Updating the video file which is replaced in DB and also storing in the folder.

**Scenario is** - While updating, if i do not select any video to update, **Empty values are going**. and getting Object not found.

Here the updating the video is not mandatory, So if i am not selecting any video, **It should retain my previous video file and should display**.

Here is *My Update Form Code*

```
<form id="My_Form" action="currentpage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" id="Edit_Vid" name="Edit_Vid">

                <?php                   
                        $output_dir = "houseadvideos/";
                          if(isset($_FILES["Edit_Vid"]))
                           {
                        if($_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["error"] > 0)
                        { 
                            $result['error'] = "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["name"]);    
                            $result['success'] = "Uploaded Document :".$_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["name"];         
                        }       
                        }
                        else{   
                        $result['error'] = 'upload document';   
                            }
                        ?>

  </form>
```

*Code to Update DB Value*

```
function UpdateForm($id,$name,$type,$dimension,$video,$duration,$uploaddate){
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }      
    $a=$varArray['upvid'];
    $file = str_replace( "\\", '/', $a );
    $ofile = basename( $file );
    $oofile ="myfolder/".$ofile;
    $date = date('m/d/Y', time()); 
    $qry ="update column_name set name='$name',type='$type',dimension='$dimension',video='$video',duration='$duration' where id=$id"; 
    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);
    return $result;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should show your code to update db value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller model binding:

```
$pathToVideo = '';

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["tmp_name"])) {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Edit_Vid"]["tmp_name"],$outp.. and so on
   //store in database
   $pathToVideo = 'the new path';
} else {
  //update model with last inserted video in database
  //SELECT FROM table WHERE user.. ODER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,0
  $pathToVideo = 'the old path';
}

//serialize your updated video path back
//render form with updated model
```

Edit after comment (how to get last video record)

```
function GetLastVideoRecord() {
    $qry ="SELECT * FROM column_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1,0"; 
    $result = mysql_query($qry, $this->connection);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row[0];
}
```

Comment: i used this. If yes. it works.. and what if it is no...?

Comment: Maybe I dindt understand you correctly. if no video is passed over the form, no changes should be made to this row in database. right?

Comment: Yes u r rite... i am storing the <input type = file> value in a variable and passing through ajax. If no video is uploaded, Empty values are going.

Comment: Ok so in that code part where you parse your model you should check something like this:

1. if video is pendant for upload store, update db and set new path to model
2. if no video is pendant, do nothing to db, store nothing and select old path from db for response.

updated my example

Comment: How you get old file and it's path ?? Not proper & complete solution.

Comment: I thought you saved your file to database? So it should be no problem to get the last inserted record..
If you want it statless, i would recomment to validate the form async and send the file as multipart encryptet upload to server (with its own file controller of course) insteat of using hidden fields in form etc.

Comment: Do you not think it's very long and hard solution for just simple issue ??

Comment: I dont think this is a very long and hard solution.. just a simple query to select the old row from db? (see updated example according to your update query).. the statless solution depends on more effort but is the clean way.. shuffling arround hidden fields only leads to confusion and overhead in postdata.